# Model loaded in Codeigniter controller's constructor is not available by other functions of same controllers

Tags: function, codeigniter, model, controller

My model: as seen below, very basic

```
class User extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getAll()
    {
        $this->db->order_by("lastName", "asc");
        $this->db->order_by("firstName", "asc");
        $this->db->order_by("userName", "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get('user');

        // test for result
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }

        return NULL;
    }
}
```

My controller: actually part of my controller, every time loading the users/display function by default route, the error (further down) shows up. Should a model loaded in a controller's contructor be available for all other function in the same controller?

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    function __contruct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user');
    }

    function display()
    {
        $data['users'] = $this->user->getAll();

        $head['pageTitle'] = 'Users Panel';

        $this->load->view('security/redirect');
        $this->load->view('template/head', $head);
        $this->load->view('user/usersPanel', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/foot');
    }
}
```

My error: refering to the line, "$data['users'] = $this->user->getAll()", in above controller

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Users::$user
```

My environment:

```
Codeigniter 2.1.0;
Mac Lion;
MAMP 2.0;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shouldn't this:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    function __contruct()
    {
```

be like this:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
```

replace contruct with construct.

Comment: this is the weirdest answer I've seen; also the most hilarious

Comment: @Lance and Yasky try looking closely at the answer. The first one contruct without s. then on the second one there is a s. :D

Comment: I spelled it the same. And I also couldn't see the difference after looking at it 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this:

```
$data['users'] = $this->user->getAll();
```

be this:

```
$data['users'] = $this->user_model->getAll();
```

**sorry** 
also the model name:

$this->load->model('user_model');

and class name User_model extends CI_Model

All of my CI projects are set up this way.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: try that already. still same errors. same as changing it to capital 'User'.

Comment: Did you try capital `User_model` in the model file and `$this->user_model` (lowercase) in the controller?

Comment: Are you using a custom model class? My CI project models extend Model, and not CI_Model.